# Can you scoop/steal a mobile tractor unit?

Tags: eve-online

Seeing the prices of mobile tractor units and their relatively small size (100 cubic metres), is it possible to scoop/steal someone's mobile tractor unit itself once the unit has been deployed by said victim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can only detroy it. Or deploy your own and let them battle it out on their own.

Comment: Tug of war MTU! :3